# Nestjs test loopLimit: fakeTimersConfig.timerLimit || 100_000

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

When I run my nestjs tests, it always returns this message:

Test suite failed to run

```
.../node_modules/@jest/fake-timers/build/modernFakeTimers.js:181
      loopLimit: fakeTimersConfig.timerLimit || 100_000,
                                                ^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@jest/fake-timers/build/index.js:21:48)
```

A can´t find any solutin for this

My node version is 12.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Changed to NPM version 18.4.0 and worked